# Newtons Method Intersection Example

Tags: calculus

I need to find the intersection of the two functions: y =ln(x) and y = -x using Newtons Method. I found the composition function to be ln(x)+x and the derivative to be 1/x +1; however, when I use the general equation I get wrong values. i.e. .5 -((ln(.5)+.5))/((1/.5)+.5)), using .5 as x_1 I get .231 as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The method is a recursive one: $$x_{n+1} = x_n - \frac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)},$$ and as you correctly computed for $f(x) = x + \log x$, ($\log$ denoting the natural logarithm), we have the recursion $$x_{n+1} = x_n - \frac{x_n + \log x_n}{1 + x_n^{-1}} = \frac{x_n (1 - \log x_n)}{1 + x_n}.$$  With the choice $x_0 = 1/2$, this gives $$x_1 = \frac{1 + \log 2}{3} \approx 0.564382.$$  Continuing to compute the recursion gives the sequence $$\{x_n\}_{n \ge 0} = \{0.5, 0.564382, 0.567139, 0.567143, 0.567143, 0.567143, \ldots \},$$ and we see by the fourth iteration that the precision of the result is at least $10^{-6}$.  In fact, the precision is quite a bit more than this; by the sixth iteration you already have at least $30$ decimal places correct.

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep iterating the method until you reach convergence.

As you say, solving the problem $\ln x = -x$ is equivalent to finding the root of $f(x) = \ln x + x$. Newton's method is an iterative algorithm to find an approximation to the real solution

$$
x_{n + 1} = x_n - \frac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)}
$$

Here are a few iterations:

```
Iteration  0: x = 0.500000
Iteration  1: x = 0.564382
Iteration  2: x = 0.567139
Iteration  3: x = 0.567143
Iteration  4: x = 0.567143
Iteration  5: x = 0.567143
Iteration  6: x = 0.567143
Iteration  7: x = 0.567143
Iteration  8: x = 0.567143
Iteration  9: x = 0.567143
```